# C++ cin from a file unspaced numbers

Tags: c++, arrays

In c++ how do i cin a file of numbers that are not spaced into an array?

For instance 78940725450327458 how could i get those numbers to be placed so that list[0] = 7, list[1] = 8, list[2] = 9 and so on.

Comment: No its for project euler

Answer (score 1):

```
std::vector<int> numList;

while(std::cin) {
    char c;
    std::cin >> c;
    if(std::cin.eof())
        break;
    if(c < '0' || c > '9') {
        // handle error
    }
    numList.push_back(c - '0');
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about C++, but would this loop execute one too many times? I thought `cin` only turns sets the failbit or badbit *after* trying to read past EOF.

Comment: Sorry, what I'm trying to say is... say there is only one character in the stream. The first `while(cin)` executes because the stream has not failed and is not bad. `cin >> c` will read the character, and the stream is still not failed or bad, so the `while(cin)` will loop again... even though there is nothing left to read.

Answer (score 0):

Make list an array of `char`s.

`cin >> list[0]` will then read a single character.

Comment: Except that it looks like Sean wants numeric values; if so, I'd cin into a single char variable, and then convert that (say, c-'0') into the corresponding integer.

Comment: Keep in mind that this would put the digit *character* into the array, not the digit's value.

Comment: @ScottHunter so how would i convert the char into an int?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to read all the line into int variable and then do the loop with something like this:

```
int temp = a % 10;
```

this will give you last number everytime, be sure to update original number after that and last thing to do is to put it into array, so thats the easy part.

Comment: That number might not fit into an `int` variable though.

Comment: so theres prety the same logic with the float or boolean, you can customize as you want.

Comment: This will lead to a lot of subtle bugs for digit strings with tens or more digits. Floats won't save you. There's no point telling the library to make an `int` by multiplying digits by 10 and adding, then immediately undoing all that work by modulusing a digit at a time (which also reverses order in the best case).

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. I'd probably do something like the following:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int ascii2int(int value) // this could be a lambda instead
{
    return value - '0';
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> nums;
    std::ifstream input("euler8Nums.txt");
    if (input)
    {
        // read character digits into vector<int>
        nums.assign(std::istream_iterator<char>(input), std::istream_iterator<char>());
        // transform ascii '0'..'9' to integer 0..9
        std::transform(nums.begin(), nums.end(), nums.begin(), ascii2int);
    }

    // your code here

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A lambda would require C++0x/C++11 (whatever it's called), right? Also, doing the assignment and conversion to number as two separate steps requires two passes through memory instead of one.